# Is there any syntaxhighlighter for SAS?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sas

I need to post SAS code on my website. However, if I do write my HTML to highlight `SAS` cod it would take me a long time.

How can I transform the SAS code into nice looking `HTML` counterpart?

Comment: Look into http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply copy/paste from your editor into a rich text editor (ie, MS Word or similar) that is capable of producing an HTML file.  Alternately, some text editors like [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) are capable of doing SAS markup.

Comment: This. Or, instead of saving the Word document as HTML, just copy/paste from Word to your favourite HTML editor.

Answer (score 5):

I just discovered that Gist actually supports SAS Syntax highlighting!

This is what you see if you create a `hello_world.sas` file on Gist.

[image]

If you'd like to embed SAS codes into (say) a Wordpress.org blog article (like myself), the way I usually do this is:

1. Create a Markdown file on [Gist](https://gist.github.com). For example, see [this Gist Markdown file that I created](https://gist.github.com/Atlas7/88fa8e14e8ced9ad9b12) ). Notice that an "embed link" is created for you:

[image]

2. In your Wordpress.org website, already have the plugin [oEmbed Gist](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oembed-gist/) already installed.
3. When you create a new blog post in Wordpress, in the body field (where you'd normally type out content of your blog post), simply copy and paste the Gist embedded link into the the body.

[image]

4. Publish that blog post and you shall see it renders beautifully!

[image]

(alternatively, if you wish to write your Wordpress blog post normally, and embed multiple Gist SAS codes, just simply save the gist files as `.sas` files (instead of one `.md` file), and embed multiple embed URLs (corresponding to each code blogs).

More info see [this stackoverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798741/how-to-fix-wordpress-wp-markdown-plugin-corrupted-syntax-highlighter-evolved-pl) - where I learnt about the awesome Gist and Wordpress Gist oEmbed combo!

Answer (score 2):

As of [SAS Entreprise Guide](http://support.sas.com/software/products/enterprise-guide/index.html) v5.1, you can right-click on the editor window and select 'Copy HTML source to clipboard'.

You can then paste the HTML directly into the HTML source of your page.

Note that this may even work in earlier versions of the [SAS Entreprise Guide](http://support.sas.com/software/products/enterprise-guide/index.html) - version 5.1 just happens to be the version I have installed.

Thanks to *@otto* for providing the original idea of using Enterprise Guide.

Answer (score 1):

I have found no **great** solution. SAS does not seem to be supported by any of the javascript highlighters.

At least three text editors I know of can export coloured HTML to the clipboard (and hence your page, or Word or PowerPoint).

1. Ultraedit
2. Notepad++
3. Emacs (ESS) (on Mac I use Aquamacs)
4. (possibly) SAS enhanced editor... not sure about this.

Another possibility is TextWrangler on Mac for which a SAS syntax colouring file is available. But I have not tried this. [update: it is not very good. many keywords missing.

A fifth possibility is SublimeText 3. It has a great syntax colouring plugin. It even gets 
    y = X * z ;
    * but this really is a comment ;
coloured correcty.
The SAS colouring package is not included by default but is downloadable from [implementing-vdw.blogspot.ch/2012/10/new-sublime-text-package-available-for.html](http://implementing-vdw.blogspot.ch/2012/10/new-sublime-text-package-available-for.html)

A trial version is free and ST is cross platform]

Somewhat off-topic -- but is the next question :-)

For preparing papers and documents there is a LaTeX package listings (which works if you use BeraMono instead of Courier) and a newer package based on it called SASnRdisplay. These packages produce great output and it is easy to add keywords. Also for listings you need to allow lowercase keywords with the sensitive=false option.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Enterprise Guide?

When I copy and paste from the EG edit window into something that supports rich text (word, an outlook email, etc), I get all of my colors and highlighting.

From here, you just have to grab the HTML and stick it online.  It may not be the prettiest HTML (WYSIWYG output rarely is), but it works.  In Outlook 2010, you can right click and "View Source" on any mails that have been sent/received (or as a trick, you can paste it into a blank email and then close it and view source in your "Drafts" folder).

As I said, it is some ugly HTML (and all on one line), but I'd assume that the output of any javascript highlighter is also fairly ugly:

```
<b><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:navy;background:white'>data</span></b><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'> test;<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>&nbsp; </span></span><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:blue;background:white'>set</span><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'> test;<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>&nbsp; </span></span><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:blue;background:white'>length</span><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'> fakevar $</span><b><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:teal;background:white'>16</span></b><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'>;<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:navy;background:white'>run</span></b><span style='font-family:"Courier New";color:black;background:white'>;</span><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
```

You can see it rendered here:
http://rendera.heroku.com/usercode/9e1bfaeb9bceb4c052d6747e8e73c1846bad433b

Answer (score 1):

I think you can the following:

- Store your codes on https://gist.github.com/
- Use the embed URL code (provided in https://gist.github.com/) in your site as...(Run Code Snippet):

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/AlyssonJalles/b22bc10a707ef909024b.js"></script>
```

*Maybe this isn't a 100% solution, but is good because when you update your code on Gist, the code will be updated in your website. Futhermore, if you use wordpress.com, you just copy the URL and paste in your page editor to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating your own HTML page (and find the gist solution undesirable), checkout CodeMirror.

http://codemirror.net/mode/sas/index.html

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode: 'sas',
  styleActiveLine: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  readOnly: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.18.2/codemirror.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.18.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>

<!-- sas language mode -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.18.2/mode/sas/sas.min.js"></script>

<!-- optional plugins -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.18.2/addon/selection/active-line.min.js"></script>

<form><textarea id="code" name="code">
libname foo "/tmp/foobar";
%let count=1;

/* Multi line
Comment
*/
data _null_;
    x=ranuni();
    * single comment;
    x2=x**2;
    sx=sqrt(x);
    if x=x2 then put "x must be 1";
    else do;
        put x=;
    end;
run;

/* embedded comment
* comment;
*/

proc glm data=sashelp.class;
    class sex;
    model weight = height sex;
run;

proc sql;
    select count(*)
    from sashelp.class;

    create table foo as
    select * from sashelp.class;

    select *
    from foo;
quit;
</textarea></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

And a sixth answer is pspad. Which has a SAS addin to get build capabilities.

http://www.pspad.com/

SAS utils here: http://www.pspad.com/en/pspad-extensions.php?stranka=3

Answer (score 0):

maybe this repo helps.

https://github.com/Jiangtang/sas.tmbundle

reference:

http://www.jiangtanghu.com/blog/2012/07/13/sublimetext2-sas/

Answer (score 0):

Emacs can do this using Emacs Speaks Statistics (ESS).  There are two contexts which I find useful for editing SAS code.  The first is `sas-mode` for editing whole SAS files, the second is using a source block within `org-mode` for literate programming.

I highly recommend reading the Emacs tutorial.  If you've just installed Emacs, just open it and press Enter (on the 'Emacs Tutorial' link).  Otherwise, press `C-h t`.

**1. Install ESS**

Press `M-x list-packages` and search for Emacs Speaks Statistics via `C-s emacs speaks statistics`.  Press `i` to mark the package for install.  Press `x` to install all marked packages.

**2. Load ESS**

To load ESS run `M-: (require 'ess-site)`.  For more details, refer to the [install instructions](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Step-by-step-instructions).

**SAS Mode**

Load SAS mode within the current buffer via `M-x sas-mode`.  This provides syntax highlighting according to your current theme.  For example, this is a light theme.

[image: sas-mode with a light theme]

**Org Mode**

Load org-mode via `M-x org-mode`.  Create a source block by typing `<s` and pressing `TAB` to autocomplete.  This creates a source code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC 

#+END_SRC
```

Then type `sas` to let Org Mode know that the source code is SAS code.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sas

#+END_SRC
```

To toggle syntax highlighting within the source block, run `M-: (setq org-src-fontify-natively t)`.

Any code within the block then takes on the syntax highlighting for SAS.  The coloring is dependent on your theme.  This is an example of a dark theme:

[image: org-mode example with dark theme]

Org-mode allows for exporting to HTML using `C-c C-e h o`.  With `htmlize`, the syntax highlighting will be exported too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merely highlight the code for programming purposes, then the best option for you as highlighted above is a text editor. I have worked on SAS for close to a decade across platforms and organizations. I find the old [crimson editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Editor) the best as it is freeware, is very light and supports many functions that are typically needed.

To ensure SAS specific syntax highlighting, you need to select the sas keyword and syntax files. These files are provided with installation only. 
Please follow the following steps
1. Install crimson editor (i am using version 3.70)
2. Click on Tools->Preferences->File->Syntax Type
3. In the syntax type, select the button with three dots on bottom right. It will give you a pop up and select sas.spc
4. In the Keywords, select the button with three dots on bottom right. It will give you a pop up and select sas.key
5. In the description type SAS
6. In the Top right frame/panel, select SAS from the last option
And you are good to go

**Edit:** The Crimson Editor can be obtained from http://www.crimsoneditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

An old question an an old programming language, but maybe somebody (like me) is still interested in yet another answer:

**How to generate SAS code highlighting using Notepad++**

1. There is a  [https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2017/08/25/npp-with-sas/] (blog entry by SAS themselves) explaining how to use syntax highlighting for SAS code in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It basically refers to a freely available Notepad++ plugin at https://github.com/cjdinger/sas-npp
2. The next step is optional: You can export the highlighted code from Notepad++ to HTML using the NppExport plugin, see e.g. https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/nppexport-for-notepad-export-highlighted-code-in-html-rtf-format/

**How to highlight SAS code in VIM**

There is a nice introduction on how to use VIM for editing SAS code from the SAS community: http://www.sascommunity.org/planet/blog/category/vim/

The basic idea is that you obtain a syntax definition file for VIM and install that, see 
https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1999

Answer (score -1):

To highlight text in a macro input the following line:

%macro __enable_eg_syntax_highlight; %mend __enable_eg_syntax_highlight;

So where everything was just black the above line will bring back the SAS formatting.

Regards Terry

Comment: This is interesting but does not really answer the question.